# React with bootstrap and Radio buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to use radio buttons in React (that I always used) but this time with `react-bootstrap`.
I have two radio buttons and I want just one to be checked and get that value.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const StandAdd = () => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState({
    kindOfStand: ""
  });

  const { kindOfStand } = item;

  const handleInputChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setItem({ ...item, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(`${kindOfStand}`);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Form.Group controlId="kindOfStand">
        <Form.Check
          type="radio"
          aria-label="radio 1"
          label="Design"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          checked={kindOfStand === "design"}
          // value="design" // <-- once enabled I can't select it
        />
        <Form.Check
          type="radio"
          aria-label="radio 2"
          label="Food"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          checked={kindOfStand === "food"}
          // value="food" // <-- once enabled I can't select it
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default StandAdd;
```

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-radio-button-1d443

any idea on how to get the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a `value` attribute to the `Form.Check`s and then get the value using `e.target.value` once you click the radio btn like this. Use `e.persist();` to avoid getting the following error:

> This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're
> seeing this, you're accessing the method currentTarget on a
> released/nullified synthetic event

```
const StandAdd = () => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState({ kindOfStand: "", another: "another" });

  const { kindOfStand } = item;

  const handleChange = e => {
    e.persist();
    console.log(e.target.value);

    setItem(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      kindOfStand: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(`${kindOfStand}`);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Form.Group controlId="kindOfStand">
        <Form.Check
          value="design"
          type="radio"
          aria-label="radio 1"
          label="Design"
          onChange={handleChange}
          checked={kindOfStand === "design"}
        />
        <Form.Check
          value="food"
          type="radio"
          aria-label="radio 2"
          label="Food"
          onChange={handleChange}
          checked={kindOfStand === "food"}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-with-bootstrap-and-radio-buttons-u3zr3)

Comment: thanks but it consoles it with no value and doesn't return any value as well

Comment: Sorry, please check again now

Comment: yes thanks. But I have to create an `item` with others values and I have to keep the syntax  `const [item, setItem] = useState({ kindOfStand: "" });` and so on. And with this doens't work

Comment: Ok. Changed it again with your original state. Have a look.

Comment: thanks. it works. I have found also anoter way with togglebuttons